# Elasticsearch Nested object Search with AND Condition

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my data in Elasticsearch - I kept Tags as nested object

```
PUT myblog/3
{
  "id" : 10003,
  "tags" : [ 
    {
      "tag" : 45647
    },
    {
    "tag" : 45648
    }
  ]
}


PUT myblog/4
{
  "id" : 10004,
  "tags" : [ 
    {
      "tag" : 45647
    }
  ]
}

PUT myblog/5
{
  "id" : 10005,
  "tags" : [ 
    {
    "tag" : 45648
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to retrieve documents with tag is 45647 & 45648. I tried it in this  way

```
GET myblog/_search
{

  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "tags",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "tags.tag": 45648}}, 
            { "match": { "tags.tag": 45647}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it is not returning the expected result. What is missing in my query to get expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You need two `nested` clauses since each nested element is a different document underneath. Try like this:

```
GET myblog/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "tags.tag": 45648
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "tags.tag": 45647
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```